# Scala using foldLeft to insert terminator between list of strings

Tags: scala, recursion, foldleft

I wrote my own recursive definition of a `foldLeft` and I'd like to use it with this function `joinTerminateLeft` which takes a list of strings and a terminator and creates a new string with those strings all separated by the terminator.

For example `List("a", "b", "c", "d")` with terminator `;` would end up being `a;b;c;d;`

Here is my `foldLeft` which I think is fine but my `terminateLeft` doesn't work for some odd reason, any idea?

```
def foldLeft [A,B] (xs:List[A], e:B, f:(B,A)=>B) : B = {
  def auxFoldLeft(xs: List[A], e: B) : B = {
    xs match {
      case Nil => e
      case x::xs => auxFoldLeft(xs, f(e, x))
    }
  }
  auxFoldLeft(xs, e)
}

def joinTerminateLeft (xs : List[String], term : String) : String = {
  def f(s: String, s2: String) : String = s + s2
  xs match {
    case Nil => ""
    case x::xs => x + foldLeft(xs, term, f)
  }
}
```

When I run `joinTerminateLeft` with a,b,c,d it stops after B for some reason and outputs the strings c,d but not with the terminator.

Comment: So this is a practice? Because `mkString(";")` works perfectly fine.

Comment: Yes it's for practice.  I need to accomplish joinTerminateLeft using my foldLeft without any additional methods besides string concatenation I'm assuming is necessary.

Comment: Plus I don't think `foldLeft` is the proper function for this, because here you don't need an initial value, to join the list as a string. A function with similar signature of `reduce` might be better suited.

Comment: It's for a homework assignment so it must be do-able.  Most definitely not the best way of doing it, but the way I'm being forced to unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is that you are using term as a starting value.  But e is an accumulator, each iteration adds onto the last.  So go through once, and you get `; + b` but the next time the accumulator is the value of that so you get `|b + c`

What you need is a different function.  Instead of adding The value to the accumulator, you need to add term to the value, then add that to the accumulator.

```
def joinTerminateLeft (xs : List[String], term : String) : String = {
  def f(s: String)(s2: String, s3: String) : String = s2 + s + s3
  xs match {
    case Nil => ""
    case x::xs => x + foldLeft(xs, "", f(term))
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but if called with a list of only one parameter it doesn't seem to work.        assert (joinTerminateLeft (List ("a"), ";") === "a;")        This returns just "a"  any idea?

Comment: The way it currently is, it will put a delimiter between values, when there is only one value, there is no "in between" space to put a delimeter.  If you simply want to enter the value after every string, change your function to put the term at the end of a string instead of the beginning `s2 + s3 +s` And instead of passing only the tail to foldLeft and adding the head on after, simple apply foldLeft to the entire list.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet that works:

```
def joinTerminateLeft (xs : List[String], term : String) : String = {
    def f(s: String, s2: String) : String = s + term + s2
    xs match {
        case Nil => ""
        case x::xs => x + foldLeft(xs, "", f)
    }
}
```

The term should only be used inside `f`. The second parameter of foldLeft is the initialization value which should be empty in this case (reduce or something similar would be more appropriate instead of fold left here).